# Always get False in checkbox value in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, kendo-ui

My kendo Code is:

```
<div id="plannedValueGrids" class="box-body no-padding" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.PlannedValues) // Bind the grid to the Model property of the view
    .Name("plannedValueGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.MetricID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.IsHistoryUpdateIfPlannedValueChanged).Title("IsHistoryUpdateIfPlannedValueChanged").Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "IsHistoryUpdateIfPlannedValueChanged", style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" }).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' value='' checked='#=IsHistoryUpdateIfPlannedValueChanged#' />");

        //columns.Bound(p => p.IsLinear).Title(Resources.Performance.IsLinear).Width(60).Sortable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.PlannedJumpOffValue).Hidden().Title(Resources.Performance.PlannedJumpOffValue).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = Resources.Performance.PlannedJumpOffValue, style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;", @class = "jumpOffA" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" }).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format(\"{0:0.0000}\", (PlannedJumpOffValue != null)? PlannedJumpOffValue:0 )#");
        columns.Bound(p => p.PlannedJumpOffRaw1).Hidden().Title(Resources.Performance.PlannedjumpOffB).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = Resources.Performance.PlannedjumpOffB, style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" }).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format(\"{0:0.0000}\", (PlannedJumpOffRaw1 != null)? PlannedJumpOffRaw1:0 )#");
        columns.Bound(p => p.PlannedTarget).Title(Resources.Performance.Planned).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = Resources.Performance.Planned, style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;", @class = "plannedA" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" }).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format(\"{0:0.0000}\", (PlannedTarget != null)? PlannedTarget:0 )#");
        columns.Bound(p => p.PlannedRaw1).Title(Resources.Performance.PlannedB).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = Resources.Performance.PlannedB, style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" }).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format(\"{0:0.0000}\", (PlannedRaw1 != null)? PlannedRaw1:0 )#");
        columns.Bound(p => p.PlannedTargetStartDate).Title(Resources.Common.StartDate).Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = Resources.Common.StartDate, style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" });
        columns.Bound(p => p.PlannedEndDate).Title(Resources.Common.EndDate).Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = Resources.Common.EndDate, style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" });
        //columns.Bound(p => p.LinearDuration).Title(Resources.Performance.LinearDuration).Column.Hidden = true;
        //columns.ForeignKey(p => p.LinearDurationUnitID, Model.MetricDurationUnits, "UnitID", "Unit").Title(Resources.Performance.Unit).Width(100).Column.Hidden = true;
        //columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Title(Resources.Common.Action).Width(60).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = Resources.Common.Action, style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" });
        //columns.Bound(p => p.IsHistoryUpdateIfPlannedValueChanged).Title("IsHistoryUpdateIfPlannedValueChanged").Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "IsHistoryUpdateIfPlannedValueChanged", style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" }).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxIsHistoryUpdateIfPlannedValueChanged'/>")
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Delete").Click("kRemovePlanned")).Title(Resources.Common.Action).Width(50).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = Resources.Common.Action, style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" });
    })
    .ToolBar(toolBar =>
    {
        toolBar.Template("<a id='kAddPlanned' class='k-grid-add' href='#'><i class='fa fa-plus-square'></i>&nbsp;" + Resources.Performance.AddPlannedValues + "</a>");
        toolBar.Save().HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "display:none" }); // The "save" command saves the changed data items
    })
    .Editable(editable => { editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell); })// Use in-cell editing mode
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
    .Batch(true) // Enable batch updates
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.MetricPlannedId);
        //model.Field(p => p.LinearDurationUnitID).DefaultValue(0);
        model.Field(p => p.MetricID).DefaultValue(0);
    })
    .ServerOperation(false)

    // Configure CRUD -->
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Home"))

    // <-- Configure CRUD
    )
    .Events(e =>
    {
        e.DataBound("kDataBoundPlanned");
        //e.Remove("kRemovePlanned");
        e.Save("kSavePlanned");
        e.Edit("kEditPlanned");
    })
    .Scrollable(src => src.Height(120)).Navigatable().Sortable()
    )


    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PlannedValuesJSON, new { @id = "hdnPlannedValues" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PlannedVaueJSONBeforeEdit, new { @id = "hdnPlannedValuesBeforeEdit" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.flag, new { @id = "hdnFlag" })
</div>`
```

And this is how i am getting the values

```
var plannedValues = kendo.stringify($("#plannedValueGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view());
//var plannedValues = $('#plannedValueGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
$("#hdnPlannedValues").val(plannedValues);
```

I have added new checkbox, and i always getting false in this. even i have checked it.

I am not able to get what i am doing wrong. please guide me

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is, if "Model.PlannedValues" list has any value then you want to check the checkbox. You can achieve the same this by using multiple ways. For reference i have provided two different ways.

Method 1:-

```
@if(Model.PlannedValues.Count() > 0)
{
<div id="plannedValueGrids" class="box-body no-padding" style="margin-top: 5px;" checked>
}
else
{
<div id="plannedValueGrids" class="box-body no-padding" style="margin-top: 5px;">
}
```

Method 2:-

```
function kDataBoundPlanned()
{
    var plannedValues = $('#plannedValueGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
    $("#hdnPlannedValues").val(plannedValues.length > 0);
}
```